# At what age can a Cat get pregnant?

Tags: cats, breeding

I met my cat 11 years ago near my flat, where she was with a kitten which had yet open eyes. I am curious about the age of my cat as my mother told me that it is common for cats to give birth to only one or two kittens from her 1st litter.

I am guessing if that is her 1st litter of kitten (only one), and I had adopt her for 11 years, what will be her current age. So what would be the approximate age when a cat can get pregnant?

Comment: With their high proliferation rate, it sometimes seems like kittens are born pregnant.

Answer (score 2):

The Humane Society website says "Cats can become pregnant as young as five months of age." I presume that's a general lower limit, with most cats either maturing or not becoming pregnant during their first heat or both.

Comment: @keshiam Oh so its around 5 months. Yes, I had did research too,but not sure about it's reliability as different webs gives different answer. I would like to seek expert view here instead. I know that veterinarians can check the estimate age of the car by looking at it's tooth. I am just curious at the moment, I will bring her to a vet to do check up soon, and ask the veterinarian. Thank you =)